# Save Grain state to the external service after some period of inactivity

Tags: .net, orleans

we are using Orleans Grain as a session, populate session with events and want to save the session to the external service after it expires (after 20 minutes of inactivity).
Initially we were going to use GrainCollectionOptions.CollectionAge to save session on deactivation, but found in different sources that it is not safe to rely on OnDeactivateAsync, because it may not always be called, especially during silo crashes or hard shutdown.

Could anybody suggest the recommended approach for such a use case?

Here is our Grain code:

```
public class SessionGrain : Grain, ISessionGrain
{
    private readonly IPersistentState<Session> _persistentState;

    public SessionGrain([PersistentState("sessionsState", "sessionsStorage")] IPersistentState<Session> persistentState)
    {
        _persistentState = persistentState;
    }

    public Task CompleteAsync()
    {
        DeactivateOnIdle();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task<Session> TrackEventAsync(Event @event)
    {
        _persistentState.State.Events.Add(@event);

        await _persistentState.WriteStateAsync();

        return _persistentState.State;
    }

    public override async Task OnActivateAsync()
    {
        if (_persistentState.State == null)
        {
            _persistentState.State = new Session();
        }

        await base.OnActivateAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDeactivateAsync()
    {
        // TODO: SAVE TO EXTERNAL SERVICE HERE???

        await _persistentState.ClearStateAsync();

        await base.OnDeactivateAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're worried that `OnDeactivateAsync` may not run if the silo crashes, but not that the same thing can happen 10 seconds before the grain is supposed to be deactivated? If you absolutely need to have the data persisted, save it immediately. If you don't, what's the difference between losing the data in 10 or 20 minutes?

Comment: Thanks @Luaan. As you can see on my code example I am using IPersistentState so should not loose anything at any point of time. At the end of the session I want to post session to the external service using HTTP, how I can do it with 100% guaranty?

Comment: You still have the same problem whether you rely on Deactivate or not - you need to have a mechanism that recovers data that's in your persistent state and not sent to your external service and deleted. This is one of the challenges of reliable and distributed software, and there's no easy solution. There's many ways to handle this depending on your requirements - a simple timer that checks the DB once in a while and tries to get the corresponding grain, deactivating it if it was newly activated, might work fine.

Answer (score 6):

If persistent state is vital and cannot be reconstructed, then you must save it immediately, before returning to the caller, so that the caller can retry in the event of a failure. Any data which has not been persisted will be lost in the event of a failure (eg, power failure, but there are many other kinds of events which result in the same behavior).

If it is acceptable to lose data in the event of a failure, then you have a couple of options:

- Save state during OnDeactivateAsync; or
- Save state after some idle time by using a timer (eg, via `this.RegisterTimer(...)`)

Comment: Thanks @ReubenBond. Persistent state is vital that's why we are using IPersistentState<Session> and save state during TrackEventAsync but the question is how to save session to another service after it expires.
In case of failure, as I understand, grain in memory is lost but its state in db is not and will be there forever as Deactivation is not called in this scenario. So relying in this case on OnDeactivateAsync is not right approach as DB will be polluted with failed grain states and never be cleared.

Comment: Are you trying to save state or delete state once it expires?

Comment: I want to delete the state from Orleans IPersistentState and make http call to external service to save the session there.

Comment: Ok, the original question says you "want to save the session to the external service after it expires".

If you want to be sure that the external service cleans up the state then you have a couple of options:

* Use a grain reminder (reliable timer) to wake up the grain after some time and ensure that its state is deleted
* Scan your storage and delete out-dated state
* Use TTL features in your storage (eg, CosmosDB offers this) to automatically delete unnecessary state